# SQL Machine Learning Services Error

Tags: python, r, sql-server, machine-learning

I am receiving the error of:

> Feature 'Advanced Analytics Extensions' is not installed

When trying to get the Machine Learning Services set up in SQL Server:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/install/sql-machine-learning-services-windows-install?view=sql-server-2017

I'm trying to execute the code:

```
 EXEC sp_configure  'external scripts enabled', 1
 RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
```

I have the R and Python services downloaded and "Advanced Analytics Extensions" is not even an option. I checked and am running the code on the instance where R/Python services were installed.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can get this up and running?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Troubleshooting R Services Setup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt695927.aspx)

Comment: What is the error when you run the sp_configure statement?  What edition of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Have you fix this problem? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you restart the instance after you added machine learning services? "Advanced Analytics Extensions" is referring to the machine learning services feature (R and Python integration). It seems like the system can't detect that the feature is installed. If you are using SSMS, you can use these rdl reports to check configuration/configure your instance:
https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/tree/master/samples/features/r-services/ssms-custom-reports

Try R Services - Configuration.rdl or R Services - Configure Instance.rdl. Add the reports to the server name in SSMS Object Explorer.